# How do I detect whether a Paragraph marker is hidden in Aspose.Words?

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose.words

I have a situation where I need to work out of a paragraph marker is hidden using Aspose.Words for .NET - while I can detect hidden runs and remove them from a document with:

```
var runs = document.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Run, true);
runs.Cast<Run>().Where(r => r.Font.Hidden).Iter(r => r.Remove());
```

This still leaves me with a paragraph split where Word itself wouldn't show one. I've had a look at the DocumentML and don't get any clues from that as it only shows the `<w:vanish />` element on the individual runs.

Does anyone have any ideas on this please?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer a couple of minutes after posting this question - look at the `ParagraphBreakFont.Hidden` property on the paragraph and that will tell you whether the paragraph marker at the end of the paragraph is hidden or not.